# Full Text Catalog size is zero

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

This morning, suddenly, my prod database full text catalog -- Catalog Size = 0. Item Count = 0, and Unique Key Count = 0 and search function return empty result.

I am using MS SQL 2012 - version 11.0.5678.0

This application running over 5 years without any problem.
[image]

Any suggestion for it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use rebuild catalog which solve the problem.
Still does not reason why it is happened, but at least it is working now for my production.